# MySQL: select into .XLS outfile vertically/targeting specific cells

Tags: mysql, sql, into-outfile

I'm trying to output one or two rows at a time from MySQL into an XLS spreadsheet, but Ideally I want it to be vertically, and I want to include the same user defined data alongside each one.

It should end up looking like this:

```
Name:  Bobby
Surname: Robson
Favorite food: Chips
```

Etc.  I'd also ideally like to include a second set of two columns.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Python package called [pyExcelerator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyexcelerator/) that can export MySQL data to Excel via Python script.  MySQL itself doesn't output in Excel binary format though.

---

EDIT:  Based on the OP's comment, here is [a Perl module for writing Excel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Excel-Writer-XLSX/) spreadsheets.  Presumably, there exists Perl support for MySQL already ;)

Comment: Ok, thanks. Don't suppose there's anything else Perl based is there?  I'm not sure I'd be allowed to install a new package on the server in question.